# DropDownListFor initial value not selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I don't understand why the initial value is not selected when the form is loaded.

Here's my code

```
model.LUIsUsed = new List<SelectListItem>()
                        {
                            new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Ignore" },
                            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Required" },
                            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Optional" },
                        };
```

In my view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Foo[i].IsUsed, Model.LUIsUsed, new { @class= "form-control input-sm is-used" })
```

`x.Foo[i].IsUsed` value is `"1"`, but `required` is not selected. I can't figure out why.

Is it because `x.Foo` is an array?

**EDIT:** When I don't use an array, it works

Comment: You see this? Old, but could still be an issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506828/mvc-2-dropdownlist-not-selecting-value-in-case-of-list

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a problem with `DropDownListFor` inside a `for` loop.

I had to build a `SelectList` and specify the selected value.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Criterias[i].IsUsed, new SelectList(Model.LUIsUsed,"Value","Text", Model.Criterias[i].IsUsed))
```

It works, but I would like to know why.